# Selenium Manager error in robotframework-selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using the latest version of the Robotframework-Seleniumlibrary 6.1.1

Since Selenium 4.10 Selenium Manager is built in and tries to find new webdrivers automatically. This, however, fails with the following warning: "Exception trying to discover chromedriver version: error sending request for URL (https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/known-good-versions-with-downloads.json): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host had failed to respond. (os error 10060)"

I suspect this might be because of my company's proxy.

This happens even when Chromedriver is in PATH and takes 105 seconds every time Chrome is opened. After which the test just runs using the chromedriver from PATH.
A workaround is specifically pointing to chromedriver in the keyword as following:

```
    Open Browser  ${URL}  Chrome executable_path=c:/Python311/chromedriver.exe
```

But this leaves a hardcoded reference and also I think executable_path might soon be deprecated in selenium.

Does anyone know of a way to point Selenium Manager (but NOT browser traffic) to the proxy, or just turn this version check off completely?

Comment: Update the question with your code trials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable selenium-manager from checking chromedriver versions by setting it in offline mode with the `--offline` switch or setting an environment variable `SE_OFFLINE=true`. At the moment (selenium 4.11.2) this will still print a warning.

You can also set the proxy for selenium-manager with `–proxy user@pass:myproxy:8080` or environment variable `SE_PROXY=user@pass:myproxy:8080`